# DataContractSerializer, appending serialization of T to serialization of List<T>

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

For the sake of learning I am trying to abstract away db access, hoping to make it possible to just plug in an XML file or a JSON file to serve data access.

Now my type has the following constructor

```
public XmlRepository(XElement root)
{
        _rootElement = root;
        Load();
}
```

The dependency(root) is supplied by an XmlContext type like this:

```
private void Load()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_fileName))
        {
            var schoolsXElement = new XElement("Schools");
            var gradesXElement = new XElement("Grades");
            var teachersXElement = new XElement("Teachers");
            var studentsXElement = new XElement("Students");

            _document = new XDocument(new XElement("DB"));
            _document.Root.Add(schoolsXElement);
            _document.Root.Add(gradesXElement);
            _document.Root.Add(teachersXElement);
            _document.Root.Add(studentsXElement);
            using (var fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                _document.Save(fs);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            _document = XDocument.Load(_fileName);
        }

        Schools = new XmlRepository<School>(_document.Root.Element("Schools"));
        Grades = new XmlRepository<Grade>(_document.Root.Element("Grades"));
        Teachers = new XmlRepository<Teacher>(_document.Root.Element("Teachers"));
        Students = new XmlRepository<Student>(_document.Root.Element("Students"));
    }
```

These methods are defined in `XmlRepository<T>` that can be called when the changes to the in-memory view of the data is to be persisted to file.

```
private void Load()
    {
        if (!_rootElement.HasElements)
        {
            _persistentStorage = new List<T>();
            _memoryStorage = new List<T>();
            return;
        }

        var xmlDeserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        var obj = xmlDeserializer.ReadObject(_rootElement.FirstNode.CreateReader()) as List<T>;
        _persistentStorage = new List<T>(obj);
        _memoryStorage = new List<T>(obj);
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        var newAdditions = _memoryStorage.Except(_persistentStorage).ToList();
        _persistentStorage.AddRange(newAdditions);
        _rootElement.RemoveAll();
        using (var fs = _rootElement.CreateWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.WriteObject(fs, _persistentStorage);
        }
    }

private void Save()
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        var newAdditions = _memoryStorage.Except(_persistentStorage).ToList();
        _persistentStorage.AddRange(newAdditions);
        _rootElement.RemoveAll();
        using (var fs = _rootElement.CreateWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.WriteObject(fs, _persistentStorage);
        }
    }
```

All of this renders the following XML (from a test run)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DB>
  <Schools>
    <ArrayOfSchool xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LearningProject.Models" />
  </Schools>
  <Grades>
    <ArrayOfClass xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="LearningProject.Models">
      <Class>
        <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LearningProject.Models">0</Id>
        <Grade>126368128361</Grade>
        <Students xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LearningProject.Models" i:nil="true" />
        <Teacher i:nil="true" />
      </Class>
      <Class>
        <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LearningProject.Models">1</Id>
        <Grade>126368128361</Grade>
        <Students xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LearningProject.Models" i:nil="true" />
        <Teacher i:nil="true" />
      </Class>
    </ArrayOfClass>
  </Grades>
  <Teachers>
    <ArrayOfTeacher xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LearningProject.Models" />
  </Teachers>
  <Students>
    <ArrayOfStudent xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LearningProject.Models" />
  </Students>
</DB>
```

Now my problem is with the save method, I don't feel comfortable deleting whatever was there and replacing it with whatever is in the persistent store. Suppose I have 10K elements there and only add 1, I would be deleting 10K elements just to be able to add 1 more.

How would I go about appending to the XML instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formats like xml simply aren't conducive to append, and no standard xml serializers supports what you want to do.

To avoid risk of data loss, you can perhaps load the existing data, add the new object, serialize **to a different file**, then swap (rename) the files.

There are other formats that are more append-friendly. For example, protobuf doesn't terminate the root element, so if you have a message of the form:

```
message SomeRoot {
    repeated SomeType items = 1;
}
```

then you can merge two lists (one on disk, one in memory) simply by appending a *second* list (with zero, one or many items) at the end of an existing file; so; a `SomeRoot` with 5 `SomeType` items simply appended with a `SomeRoot` with 3 `SomeType` items is *identical* to a `SomeRoot` with 8 `SomeType` items.

Comment: I suppose I don't have a choice then with the built-in library, my intuition says what I want to achieve should be possible, but not at this stage of my know-how of C# :)